# Wordpress redirects to default.aspx

Tags: wordpress

I've got a problem with my website redirect:

If i use this link:
"www.example.com" it works fine.
But with "example.com" it redirects to "www.example.com/default.aspx".

This is my htacces file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Any ideas?
Tried a lot in Htacces but it might be me but I can't seem to get it working.
It's hosted in Cpanel with a dedicated server.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some more details about the question because it is not clear.

Comment: sounds like you have an old app.config lying around and aren't using Apache 2